# Show that for $\sigma \in [-1,1]$ and $\tau \in \mathbb{C}$: $f_{\tau}\circ f_{\sigma}=f_{\sigma \tau }$

Tags: complex-analysis

For $ \sigma \in \mathbb{C}$ is

\begin{align*}
f_{\sigma}:\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z\rightarrow e^{\sigma \ln(z)}
\end{align*}

show that for $\sigma \in [-1,1]$ and  $\tau \in \mathbb{C}$ is $f_{\tau}\circ f_{\sigma}=f_{\sigma \tau }$

ok one question what do i do with the nexus $\circ$?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: and why should i if its all under the same function.?

Comment: Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: ok and now you will grumble at me because i have no idea haha.

Comment: You've been for 6 months on this site, having asked 5 questions. You should know already that it is encouraged to include your own work/thoughts/... in a question. Show us where you are stuck.

Comment: nice to meet you. if i dont have an idea what should i say? the beginning is mostly the problem. isnt this a site for help? i want help, maybe a hint or advice what to do

Comment: Sure, this is a site for help, but your question like it is now stated seems more like 'please, do my homework'. Therefore, if you have tried anything, include it in your question. If you struggle with how to start, just write that down :) Anyway, see my hints in the answers. Try to use them and update your question with what you came up so far.